# Groupby and perform aggregation with multiple functions in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

```
date          in   out  balance

01/01/2017    50    70    100
02/01/2017    100   10    190
...           ...   ...   ...
```

I am creating a summary file (grouped by month) with the following code:

```
df2 = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='M'))
df2 = df.agg({'total_in': 'sum', 'total_out': 'sum', 'balance': 'last'})
```

However, I also want to create 'largest in' and 'largest out' columns.

I tried the following

```
df2 = df2.agg({'total_in': 'sum', 'total_out': 'sum', 'largest in': 'max', 'largest out': 'max', 'balance': 'last'})
```

However, this throws a Key Error for the new columns. 
I had hoped that I could create new columns in the Agg statement, but this appears not to be the case.

Now I could off course add this columns in the normal database - but those values would be relatively meaningless on a per day basis, and it seems to be a waste of processing power / something that should be able to be done more efficiently.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: No, this isn't how it works. The key is the column to act on. The value is a function, or a list of functions.

Comment: You can do `{'total_in': ['sum', 'max']...}` to apply multiple aggregations but you'll end up with a leveled column for `total_in`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things to note here -

1. `agg` takes a `dict`. In this case, the key is the column to perform an aggregation on, and the value is a function, or list of functions.
2. `pd.TimeGrouper` is deprecated (as of `v0.21`). Use `pd.Grouper` instead.

This is what I'd recommend doing, assuming `date` is not part of the index -

```
f = {
        'in'      :  [('total_in', sum), ('largest_in', max)], 
        'out'     :  [('total_out', sum), ('largest_out', max)], 
        'balance' :  'last'
}
df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='1M')).agg(f)
```

Each tuple consists of two elements - the first element (example, `total_in`) is the name of the resultant column, while the second element (example, `sum`) is the function to apply on the key. The output will be a dataframe with a `MultiIndex` column.

Note that you can just drop the `key='date'` bit if `date` is already a part of the index.

Comment: I was able to use your code to create the CSV I desired. Many thanks (and a happy new year!)